# Chrome, recover history in incognito before tab closing

Tags: google-chrome, privacy, history

as many articles here said, google chrome removes history in incognito mode only when last incognito table is closed. So from this comes my question, is here posibility to access this history (when incognito table from this session is still opened)? What i know is that in incognito mode, history button is grayed out. But maybe there is another posibility how to acces it?

Comment: If you could access it it wouldn't be **incognito** would it.

Answer (score 0):

Full back/forward history of indivual tabs , or just the list of currently opened tabs ?

If you use an extension* that provides the feature, and specifically enable it in incognito mode, then yes.

*most session manager and undo closed tab extensions.